# Issues with pip installing on Git Bash

Tags: bash, git, pip

I've been having a couple issues with pip installing on Git Bash, every time I try to pip install I get the same error and I've searched for the same error but they are all fixes for different terminals, I hope you can help

[image: See image below]

Thank you if you can help!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score -1):

Removed all my Python installs and scripts, got it working!